# How to set a variable name with a variable?

Tags: variables, symbols, let-binding, setq

I want to do this.

```lisp
(let ((myvar "my/variable")
      (myval "Some Value"))
  (setq myvar myval))
```

The manual method is:

```lisp
(setq "my/variable" "Some Value")
```

Here is the full code: As you can see the values are shown in the messages area but they are not set as variables.

```lisp
(define-error 'my-own-errors   "My Errors")
(define-error 'wrong-arguments "Wrong Arguments" 'my-own-errors)
(define-error 'file-missing    "File Missing"    'my-own-errors)
(define-error 'unknown         "Unknown Error"   'my-own-errors)

(defun my/map--nested-alist (callback NLIST)
  "Call CALLBACK with key value pairs."
  (cond ((stringp NLIST)
         (unless (file-exists-p NLIST)
           (error (signal 'file-missing '(NLIST "was not found.")))))
        ((not (listp NLIST))
         (error (signal 'wrong-arguments '(NLIST "is not a list"))))
        ((listp NLIST) ; Ideally check the list for (dot . notation)
         t)
        (t
         (error (signal 'unknown '(NLIST "was not found.")))))
  (dotimes (x (length NLIST))
    (let* ((group (nth x NLIST))
           (cl (nth 0 (cdr group))) ; cons or list
           (key (car group))
           ;; if list use nth if cons (foo . bar) use cdr
           (val1 (if (consp cl)
                     (car cl)
                   (nth 0 cl)))
           ;; TODO: I could not figure out how to account for cons (dot . notation)
           ;; for now don’t use a '.' in the file, will look at it later.
           (val2 (if (consp cl)
                     (nth 1 cl)
                   (cdr cl))))
      (funcall callback
               `(:key ,key :val1 ,val1 :val2 ,val2)))))

(my/map--nested-alist (lambda (x)
                        (let* ((key   (format "%s" (plist-get x :key)))
                               (myvar (format "%s" (plist-get x :val1))))
                          (progn
                            (message "key is: %s val: %s" key myvar)
                            (setq key myvar))))
                      (with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents "~/.config/emacs/.data/fakefile")
                                        (read (buffer-string))))
```

Here is the file in `~/.config/emacs/.data/fakefile`

```lisp
(("my/website"  ("~/Documents/website"  "Website stuff Comment"))
 ("my/journals" ("~/Documents/journals"                     nil))
 ("my/example"  ("~/Documents/example"        "Example Comment")))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew let* don't work.

Comment: The variable needs to be a symbol, not a string: `'my/variable`, not `"my/variable"`.

Comment: @Drew that don't work `(let* ((myvar 'my/variable).....`

Comment: See [Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variables.html) in the Emacs Lisp reference manual, but you might profit from a basic Lisp introduction (I like "The Little Lisper" by Friedman and Felleisen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intern` turns a string into a symbol, then you can use `set` on that symbol:

```lisp
(set (intern "var") "some value")
var
⇒ "some value"
```

or

```lisp
(setq varname "var")
(set (intern varname) "some value")
var
⇒ "some value"
```

`(setq NAME VALUE)` is a contraction of `(set 'NAME VALUE)` (notice the quote, hence the "q"). `setq` suppresses the evaluation of its first argument (think about it, most Elisp function would expand `NAME` to its value as a variable, e.g. `(concat var "some string")`. In fact, `setq` isn't a function, it is a special form). You don't need this when you invoke `intern`, that's why you use `set`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable needs to be a symbol, not a string: `my/variable`, not `"my/variable"`.

```lisp
(let ((myvar 'my/variable)
      (myval "Some Value"))
  (set myvar myval)
  (message "MYVAR: %S" myvar))
```

Of course, if you want to change a global (i.e., dynamically bound) variable named `my/variable` then you need to declare it as such:

```lisp
(defvar my/variable "Some Value")
```

Or

```lisp
(defvar my/variable)

(let ((myval "Some Value"))
  (setq my/variable myval))
```

Or even just this (not inside a `let`):

```lisp
(setq my/variable "Some Value")
```

It all depends on what you want to do. What that is isn't clear.

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: @ritchie It *does* work, so... please update your question to show precisely what you're doing (including precisely how you're testing it).

Comment: @phils I updated it with the full example to show how it does not work in my code. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're still using `setq` rather than `set` as Drew showed you.

Comment: @phils Removing the 'q' and using set only gives me "Wrong type argument: symbolp, "my/website". I understand that set needs the first argument to be a SYMBOL. I don't understand how I can make this work.

Comment: The answer to your question is nevertheless to use `set`.  With a variable `VAR` set to a symbol value, `(set VAR VALUE)` will assign `VALUE` to that symbol.  Which is what you asked how to do.  Anything else is just debugging (in your case `"my/website"` is a string and you need to use a symbol -- Drew *also* pointed this out in the answer).

Comment: @phils set alone was not working I ended up using `intern`, which made the code work as Arch Stanton suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure (and that's a very good thing to know), but you can also *not use a string in the first place* if you don't need to be doing that.  Is there anywhere that you need the value `"my/website"` as a string?  If not, make it a symbol and then you won't need to intern it.